# find the value of the following (real) integral

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

$$\int_0^{+\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+9)(x^2+4)} \, dx = \int_0^{+\infty}f(x) \, dx$$

Here is my attempt, if you could please look over it and tell me if it's correct or not:

First of all, the integral converges, because there are no poles in the real axis, and the degree of the denominator is more than 2 units higher than the degree of the numerator.

Now, according to the book I'm using:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}R(x) \, dx=2\pi i \sum \operatorname{Res} R(z) \tag 1$$

Because if you integrate f(z) over a closed curve consisting of the segment $(-r,r)$, and the semicircle from $r$ to $-r$, the integral of the arc tends to 0, when $r$ tends to infinite.

So, if instead of using a segment centered at the origin, I use a segment between 0 and infinity, and the correspondent semicircle, is the integral of the arc also 0?

If that is the case then calculating the residues and applying 1) should solve the integral.

Comment: Just notice that $$\int_{0}^{+\infty }\frac{x^{2}}{\left( x^{2}+9\right)
\left( x^{2}+4\right) }dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }\frac{x^{2}}{
\left( x^{2}+9\right) \left( x^{2}+4\right) }dx$$ and apply 1).

Comment: First note that the very first equality in your question doesn't uniquely determine $f$. Secondly, "I use a segment between 0 and infinity, and the correspondent semicircle", what semicircle?

Comment: Why do you DO NOT want to use the contour as the semicircle centered at the origin?

Comment: I'm assuming that you are supposed to use complex methods, so this is not an answer.  But of course the integral is quite easy by standard real methods:$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x^2+9)(x^2+4)}\,dx=\frac{1}{5}\int_0^\infty \frac{9}{x^2+9}\,dx-\frac{1}{5}\int_0^\infty \frac{4}{x^2+4}\,dx=\hbox{etc}\ .$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider $\large\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(x^2+9)(x^2+4)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+9)(x^2+4)}dx$

Because the integrand has no poles in the segment you are attempting to use.

the poles occur at $z=\pm 3i,\pm 2i$, if we consider the upper semi circle, spanning across $-\infty$ to $\infty$, the two poles in the semi circle are $2i,3i$.

Let $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{(z^2+9)(z^2+4)}$

We see that $Res(f,2i)=\large\lim_{z\to 2i}\frac{z^2}{(z^2+9)(z+2i)}=\frac{-4}{5(4i)}=-\frac{1}{5i}$

and $Res(f,3i)=\frac{-9}{(6i)(-5)}=\frac{3}{10i}$

Thus $\large\int_0^\infty\frac{x^2}{(x^2+9)(x^2+4)}dx=\frac{1}{2}(2\pi i)(\frac{-1}{5i}+\frac{3}{10i})=\pi(\frac{3}{10}-\frac{2}{10})=\frac{1}{10}\pi$.

Comment: thanks! missing $f$'s simmetry was a big blunder indeed